# Pass and access custom variable in nextauth using googleProvider

Tags: authentication, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth, next.js13

I want to pass custom `role` variable from signIn button using googleProvider. In my database there are two roles (seller and user). I want to sign in both users using google oauth. I want to pass `role` variable to know which user is about to signin/signup.

problem is that I can not pass data from signin page to [...nextauth].js .

```
signIn('google', { role: Role.SELLER })
```

[...nextauth]

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
      profile(profile: any) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          email: profile.email,
          name: profile.name,
          profile: profile.picture,
          username: faker.helpers.slugify(
            profile.name.toLowerCase() +
              faker.datatype.number({ min: 100, max: 999 })
          ),
          emailVerified: profile.email_verified,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
});
```

I am expecting `role` variable from client and save it to the database. I am very new to nextauth so i dont know to use it properly.